# Catching specific error on Stripe PHP to display custom message

Tags: php, error-handling, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe payment gateway with the credit card details to input.

It is working fine but there is one error message that I don't like but I am not advanced enough in PHP to fix this.

```
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
            if (response.error) {
                // Enable the submit button
                $('#payBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                // Display the errors on the form

                $(".payment-status").html('<p>'+response.error.message+'</p>');

            } else {
                var form$ = $("#paymentFrm");
                // Get token id
                var token = response.id;
                // Insert the token into the form
                form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "' />");

                // Submit form to the server
                form$.get(0).submit();
            }
        }
```

This is catching the errors and displaying response.error.message

These errors are great with the exception of if you write a bunch of numbers into the expiry instead of mm/yy.

the error returned is:

> The 'exp_year' parameter should be an integer (instead, is
>   20undefined).

I don't know enough about this language but I want to catch this specific error and just say something like "The expiry date is incorrect, please enter as MM/YY"

I tried doing an if statement to read response.error.message but I didn't know how to format well. I tried also finding an error.code instead of message to use however the code invalid_number comes up but if I use this in an IF statement it refers to all invalid numbers of all fields (including card number) so my expiry statement is obviously incorrect in this situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually JavaScript, not PHP. You probably have this code in a PHP file somewhere which you are rendering on the server, but this is JavaScript code which will run on the client.

It sounds like you are using Stripe.js v2 for your integration. This is discouraged as Stripe.js v2 is deprecated. Instead you should use [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web), which will handle all the validation you are after here for you.

The above link shows you how to create payments with PaymentIntents, the newest and most feature rich API from Stripe. If you however want to continue using the Charge API, you can see how to use it with Elements here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges

Comment: Thanks for that. I had it made by a freelancer and I requested Stripe Elements.. this is quite annoying, I will have to contact them.